# Cycle remove from linklist gives segmentfault

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void removeLoop(Node* head)
{
    // code here
    // just remove the loop without losing any nodes
    Node* rab=head;
    Node* tur=head;
    while(rab  && rab->next)
    {
        rab=rab->next->next;
        tur=tur->next;
        if(tur==rab)
        break;
    }
    Node* temp=NULL;
    if(rab && rab->next)
    {
        
        rab=head;
        while(rab!=tur)
        {
            rab=rab->next;
            temp=tur;
            tur=tur->next;
        }
        temp->next=NULL;
    }
}
```

This is my code implemented using floyd algo.

Question link
https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/remove-loop-in-linked-list/1#

It is giving segment fault on submission not able to identify the particular test case it's failing

According to question no need to return anything.

Comment: Far as I can tell, the second loop would run forever, the condition `rab != tur` is always true. In that loop, `rab` and `tur` advance at the same speed, but generally start at different positions. And if, by coincidence, the loop closed exactly at `head` and `rab` and `tur` are equal from the start, then `temp` is never assigned a value other than null, and `temp->next=NULL` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: But according to floyd algorithm we find start of loop like this.

Comment: Either you misunderstood the algorithm, or implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: See first time one pointer moves faster and after we get the meeting node both start at same speed one from head and one from meeting point to find the starting node of loop.And here I am trying to delete that after finding it.    Please tell where am i getting it wrong. I am stuck for long time.

Comment: Ah, I see. The bug is only when the meeting point is `head`, when the loop is `o`-shaped and not `b`-shaped. In this case, `tur == head`, and so `rab == tur` from the start, the second `while` loop never executes and `temp` is never assigned a non-null value.

Comment: Ok now it works thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

If we take the input as

```
4
1 2 3 4
1
```

then it will show the segmentation error.
Reason: If you run the code on this specific testcase, then after running the first while loop, both tur and rab will point to the head of the list. Now the condition of while loop inside the if loop will always return false. And after that, the code on the next line `temp->next=NULL` will give error  because temp was initially NULL and this line will exhibit undefined behavior.
The correct program should be:

```cpp
void removeLoop(Node* head)
{
    Node* rab=head;
    Node* tur=head;
    
    while (rab && rab->next) {
        rab = rab->next->next;
        tur = tur->next;
 
        if (rab == tur)
            break;
    }
 
    if (tur == rab)
    {
        tur = head;
           
        if(tur == rab) {
            while(rab->next != tur) rab = rab->next;
        }
        else {
            while (tur->next != rab->next) {
                rab = rab->next;
                tur = tur->next;
            }
        }
 
        rab->next = NULL;
    }
}
```